# Merge results of two SUM DISTINCT queries in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have the below two separate statements querying the same table, in each case a select distinct is applied to a column and then another column summed.

```
 SELECT 
    HomeTeam, SUM(FTHG)
 FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT HomeTeam, FTHG FROM Football_Stats.E0_1617) AS alias_name
 GROUP BY
    HomeTeam


 SELECT 
    AwayTeam, SUM(FTAG)
 FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT AwayTeam, FTAG FROM Football_Stats.E0_1617) AS alias_name
 GROUP BY
    AwayTeam
```

The results for the select distinct (but not the sum) will be the same, is it possible to return combined results with a single query to something like the below:

Team    SUM(FTHG)    SUM(FTAG)

Would this require joining two temporary tables?

Apologies I have not posted an example table, I struggled with the formatting.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please add the scema and sample data. That'll be really helpful to solve your question.

Comment: Summing numbers from a select distinct result is almost always incorrect. `Id=1 Team=x goals=3, id=2 team=x goals=3` correct sum of goals=6 but sum of select distinct team,goals = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is first adding both query results using UNION ALL (but creating different columns for FTHG and FTAG), and then combining rows grouping by team again...

```
SELECT Team,SUM(FTHGSum),SUM(FTAGSum)
FROM 
    ((SELECT HomeTeam AS Team,SUM(FTHG) AS FTHGSum,0 AS FTAGSum FROM (SELECT DISTINCT HomeTeam,FTHG FROM ZTesting) T1 GROUP BY HomeTeam)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT AwayTeam AS Team,0 AS FTHGSum,SUM(FTAG) AS FTAGSum FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AwayTeam,FTAG FROM ZTesting) T2 GROUP BY AwayTeam)) AS T
GROUP BY Team
```

**NOTE**: Sorry for asking, but... do you know that using `DISTINCT` with multiple columns applies the distinction to the column combination? It's just that seemed strange to me that in your queries, the sum of goals you're getting is not of all matches for each team (you are missing matches where the team score the same number of goals). But of course, I'm just guessing, I don't know your specific case...

I hope it helps